# Docker compose : MySQL with NodeJS "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, mysql-8.0

Trying to run NodeJS server and MySQL db with docker-compose but no matter what I do I can't connect both together.

Here is what I get in console :

```
api      | Listening
api      | Connecting with {"host":"mysql","database":"bogo_plan","user":"root","port":3006}
api      | /app/index.js:24
api      |   if (err) throw err;
api      |            ^
api      | 
api      | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.27.0.2:3006
api      |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
api      |     --------------------
api      |     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
api      |     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
api      |     at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
api      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:23:5)
api      |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
api      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
api      |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
api      |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
api      |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
api      |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
api      |   errno: -111,
api      |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
api      |   syscall: 'connect',
api      |   address: '172.27.0.2',
api      |   port: 3006,
api      |   fatal: true
api      | }
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: 'mysql'
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    ports:
      - '3006:3006'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/my-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bogo_plan
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
  api:
    container_name: 'api'
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./api
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    restart:
      always
    volumes:
      - /api/node_modules
      - ./api:/api
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bogo_plan
```

I can connect to the mysql container using mysql cli and do whatever I want in it. I know I'm connected to the right one because the database has been created when I first log into the database.

I tried many things :

- Changing the hostname in the API to hardcode the one I used to connect with CLI (although it was the same)
- Changing the containers' names
- Setting a delay before I attempt to connect with the API using setTimeout()
- Setting passwords
- I saw somewhere that maybe the MySQL version could not work with TCP
  protocol, so I tried connecting to the container's DB using `mysql -h 172.27.0.2 --protocol=TCP -u root -p` and I could connect without any issue.

At this point, I'm out of idea.

**EDIT :** took out some irrelevant part of the question so it's more easily readable.

Comment: The port for the mysql database looks wrong. `3306` is the default, but the `docker-compose.yml` uses `3006`.

Comment: I changed for 3306:3306 and the error message changes. It's almost embarassing, but thanks a lot no matter how many times I looked at the file I didn't notice this ... Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses port number **3306**, not **3006** as you have in your `docker-compose` file, as [Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771444/docker-compose-mysql-with-nodejs-error-connect-econnrefused/66771666?noredirect=1#comment118032170_66771444) mentioned in the OP's comment.

You should `mysql` instance service in `docker-compose` port mapping:

```
ports:
  - "3006:3306"
```

Comment: This alone will not solve the problem. Also, you could've at least referenced my comment.

Comment: I did not notice your comment, I just saw the question and issue, then wrote the answer.